# Connect multiple mongodbs, running on different aws servers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-services, amazon-web-services, connection

I am new to nodejs and I am facing an issue when I try to connect multiple mongodbs, running on different aws servers.

I have used `tunnel-ssh` but it shows failed to connect.

Can anyone provide me some information on how to connect multiple mongodbs, running on different aws servers within a single nodejs application?

```js
const fs=require('fs')
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');
var config = {
      username:'ubuntu',
      host:'my.ip.address',
      agent : process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
      privateKey:require('fs').readFileSync('C:\Users\\Ronit\\Downloads\\my.ppk'),
      port:19735,
      dstHost:'Database server Ip address',
      dstPort:19735,
      localHost:'127.0.0.1',
      //password:'mypassword',
      localPort: 19735,
      keepAlive:true
  };
var server = tunnel(config, function (error, server) {
    if(error){
        console.log("SSH connection error: " + error);
    }
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:19735/test');

    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'DB connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function() {
        // we're connected!
        console.log("DB connection successful");
    });
});
```

```js
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED my_ip:19735
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1077:14)
```

Comment: When you say 'connect', do you mean that you want to join them in a [replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/)? In any case, can you describe in more detail exactly how you try to connect them and what the exact result is?

Comment: @VinceBowdren I have edited my post with the code and error,please look into this.I think that will certainly help you to understand my problem.